# Schur-Zassenhaus, Frattini's argument

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a questions regarding an application of the theorem of Schur-Zassenhaus and/or Frattini's argument. I am trying to figure out the following:

Let $p\geq n$ and $G<\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ be a subgroup, where $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Let $P<G$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup and $G^+<G$ the subgroup of $G$ generated by the elements $g\in G$ with $g^p=1$. We know that $p \nmid[G:G^+]$.

Now I want to deduce, that $$G= G^+ N_G(P),$$
where $N_G(P)$ denotes the normalizer of $P$ in $G$. I thought of using Frattini's argument, which however only works if $G^+$ is normal. 
Does anyone know, how to deduce the general case? The fact $p\nmid [G:G^+]$ looks like Schur-Zassenhaus, but it is not directly applicable and I don't know how to do it.

Thank in advance for any hints.

Comment: Your subgroup $G^+$ of $G$ is normal (in fact it is characteristic). The proof is straightforward.

Comment: why would that be true if $G$ is not commutative? For $g,h\in G^+$, it is $(gh)^p\neq 1$. Also for $i\in G$ I don't see, why $i ghi^{-1}\in G$.

Comment: $ighi^{-1} = (igi^{-1})(ihi^{-1}) \in G^+$.